# Setting environment variable 'TURTLEBOT_STAGE_MAP_FILE'

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to get the turtlebot stage simulator running from these instructions: http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot_stage/T...

But, putting the first line in the terminal:

```
roslaunch turtlebot_stage turtlebot_in_stage.launch
```

gives this output:

```
... logging to /home/yaseen-14/.ros/log/0b120c28-319b-11e5-ac3b-685d4316eccf/roslaunch-yaseen14-HP-Pavilion-m6-Notebook-PC-11910.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

Invalid <arg> tag: environment variable 'TURTLEBOT_STAGE_MAP_FILE' is not set. 

Arg xml is <arg default=" $(env TURTLEBOT_STAGE_MAP_FILE)" name="map_file"/>
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

Not sure why this is happening but would appreciate if anyone could help me out. Cheers!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/216318/setting-environment-variable-%27turtlebot_stage_map_file%27/) by [DENSO](https://answers.ros.org/users/23590/denso/) on ROS Answers with karma: 37 on 2015-08-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can refer to this [page](http://answers.ros.org/question/214452/setting-environment-variable-turtlebot_stage_map_file/).

---

Originally posted by [Fighting_bird](https://answers.ros.org/users/26255/fighting_bird/) with karma: 72 on 2016-06-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0